# Responsive view from mobile not showing search fields

Tags: php

I have a problem my responsive view: its not showing search fields from mobile, but on desktop it is 100% OK!! Below is "search.php"

```php
<!-- mobile  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#filtr-mobile').click(function() {
            $("#tab-search-mobile").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
        <div class="mobile_bar">
            <div id="filtr-mobile" class="btnm">
            <i class="fa fa-sliders" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span><?php _e('Search', 'katrina'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="tab-search-mobile" style="display:none">
                <div>
                <div class="filters">
                    <form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" class="search nocsrf" method="get">
                        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="sOrder" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_order()); ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="iOrderType" value="<?php $allowedTypesForSorting = Search::getAllowedTypesForSorting(); echo osc_esc_html($allowedTypesForSorting[osc_search_order_type()]); ?>" />
                        <?php foreach(osc_search_user() as $userId) { ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="sUser[]" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html($userId); ?>" />
                        <?php } ?>


                        <div class="row one_input">
                            <span class="valuess border-radius">
                                <input type="text" name="sPattern" id="query" placeholder="<?php echo osc_esc_html(__($sQuery));  ?>" value="" />
                                </span>

                        </div>

                        <fieldset class="box location">

            <?php $aCountries = Country::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>

                        <div class="row" <?php if(count($aCountries) <= 1 ) {?>style="display:none;"<?php } ?>>
                          <h4><?php _e('Country', 'katrina') ; ?></h4>

                          <?php
                            $s_country = Country::newInstance()->listAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Share your demo page. Then only we find out the responsive issue for the search box.

Comment: this is the site  al3araba.website

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer